# how to float modern-tab links to the left?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, modern-ui

I've searched for how to float the modern-tab (layout-ed as list) links to the left for my project, unfortunately no result found :/
please guys any idea ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The horizontal alignment is hard-coded to right. You would need to replace the control template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ModernTab">
                    <Grid>
                        <!-- link list -->
                        <ListBox x:Name="LinkList" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Links}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="{DynamicResource HeaderMargin}"
                                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                                 ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both">
                            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuText}" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Ideal" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuText}" />
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,0,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter"
                                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuTextHover}"/>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuTextSelected}"/>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName, Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>

                        <!-- content -->
                        <controls:ModernFrame Source="{Binding SelectedSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" ContentLoader="{TemplateBinding ContentLoader}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I can't seem to find anywhere else that gives another answer other than changing the control template. Setting the horizontal alignment did it for me:

```
<mui:ModernTab Layout="Tab" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <mui:ModernTab.Links>
                <!-- TODO: set @Source -->
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Connect" Source="/Pages/Tab1.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Diagnostics"  Source="/Pages/Tab2.xaml" />
            </mui:ModernTab.Links>
        </mui:ModernTab>
```